java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ConfigurationProperties annotation found on 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebProperties$Resources'
When i change spring-boot-starter-parent from 2.3.7 to 2.7.10 ，it appear this error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ConfigurationProperties annotation found on  'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebProperties$Resources'.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97) ~[spring-core-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.registerBeanDefinition(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.java:87) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.register(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.java:61) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.register(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.java:55) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(EnableConfigurationPropertiesRegistrar.java:49) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:86) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:396) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:986) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:395) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:157) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:748) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]

<spring-boot.version>2.7.10</spring-boot.version>
<spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
